# ePub input fields and email content?

Tags: user-input, email, epub

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGGYx.png)My church has started using The Church App. Within the app, the user can input information that the app saves.  It also gives the option to email that as a PDF to themselves.

In the attached image, the input box was used is in green.  The input boxes that can be used are in blue.  Can that be created in an ePub?

Comment: What? You can automagically generate *.epub as well as pdfs. Or it's not the question?

Comment: Within a page of an input can fields be inserts where the user can input information then emails to themselves.

Comment: This seams like a question about particular application and it's capabilities. So, I'm voting for move to Super User. Please consider enhancing Your question a little bit more. Because it's totally unclear what exactly are You asking. Most of the times, everything is possible.

Comment: The comment has been updated with images